# $\det(B\cdot A\cdot B^T)\neq0$ if and only if $\ker(B^T)=\{\bar{0}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we have:

$A$, $n\times n$ matrix non singular.

$B$, $m\times n$ matrix.

How would we prove that $\det(B\cdot A\cdot B^T)\neq0$ if and only if $\ker(B^T)=\{\bar{0}\}$.

Comment: Where are you stuck at? One direction is really easy. But, as julien remarks, some hypotheses are missing.

Comment: @user52045 No go, as $B$ need not be quadratic.

Comment: Yes, I guess that hypothesis was missing in my notes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false. Take
$$
B=\pmatrix{1&0}\quad B^T=\pmatrix{1\\0}\quad A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0} \quad \Rightarrow \quad BAB^T=(0)
$$

If $B$ is square, the equivalence is obvious by determinant considerations.

The direction $\Rightarrow$ is always true and easy: if $BAB^T$ is injective, so is $B^T$.

The converse is true if, for instance, $A$ is symmetric positive definite. Indeed, if $B^T$ is injective, and if $BAB^Tx=0$, let $C$ be the positive square root of $A$, which is also symmetric positive definite. Then
$$
BAB^Tx=0\Rightarrow x^TBC^2B^Tx=0\Rightarrow (CB^Tx)^TCB^Tx=0$$
$$\Rightarrow CB^Tx=0\Rightarrow B^Tx=0\Rightarrow x=0  
$$
i.e. $BAB^T$ is injective, hence invertible by rank-nullity.

Comment: $\ker(B^t)\neq\{0\}$ ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe...? No...

Comment: “How would we prove that $\det(B\cdot A\cdot B^T)\neq0$ *if and only if $\ker(B^T)=\{\bar{0}\}$.*”

Comment: @MichaelHoppe ? We can't because it is false. I gave an example that has $\det(BAB^T)=0$ and yet $\ker B^T=\{0\}$.

Comment: One may choose $B^T=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yeahh well, one can also make a counterexample with a $2\times 257$ matrix... I think mine is minimal. Unless I am not awake enough.

Comment: Am I missing something? Let $B^T=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$. Then clearly the rank of $B^T$ is one, hence the dimension of it's kernel $2-1=1$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  The domain is one-dimensional here. So $1-1=0$.

Comment: Ok, I see, you're correct.